# Extending a Java class in Scala while keeping the field accessible

Tags: java, scala, libgdx

I'm about to write a 2d game using LibGDX which has nice classes like `Vector2`.

Since I'm writing in functional fashion (copying, pattern matching, etc.) I'd like it to be a case class.

Because it's not one, I decided to try to extend it without success:

```scala
import com.badlogic.gdx

class Vector2(x: Float, y: Float) extends gdx.math.Vector2(x, y) {
  def copy(x: Float = this.x, y: Float = this.y): Vector2 = {
    new Vector2(x, y)
  }
}

object Vector2 {
  def apply(x: Float = 0, y: Float = 0): Vector2 = {
    new Vector2(x, y)
  }
}
```

The problem is that the following throws `println(Vector2(1, 2).x)` because there's no `x` field.

If I write it like `class Vector2(override val x: Float, override val y: Float)` it throws:

> overriding variable x in class Vector2 of type Float;  value x has
>   incompatible type class Vector2(override val x: Float,
>   override val y: Float) extends gdx.math.Vector2(x, y) {

I'm unable to get this to work. I also tried `var` instead and `java.lang.Float` without success.

Edit: It seems that it's not possible, because Scala generators a function and there's no equivalent function in Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shadowing the `x` you want.

People are often annoyed by this need to rename class parameters to avoid creating fields.

See [this symptom](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5114) and [the shadowing issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4762).

In this case, it results in an interop problem.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Vector2(x0: Float, y0: Float) extends gdx.math.Vector2(x0, y0) {
  def copy(x: Float = this.x, y: Float = this.y): Vector2 = {
    new Vector2(x, y)
  }
}

object Vector2 {
  def apply(x: Float = 0, y: Float = 0): Vector2 = {
    new Vector2(x, y)
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Vector2
defined object Vector2

scala> Vector2(1, 2).x
res1: Float = 1.0
```

Footnote:

Before,

```
scala> Vector2(1, 2).x
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field Vector2.x from class 
  ... 40 elided
```

because `this.x` creates a private field in the subclass.

The erroneous expression shouldn't be trying to access that field; in the absence of an accessor `x`, it should

```
scala> (Vector2(1,2): gdx.math.Vector2).x
res2: Float = 1.0
```

You can't circumvent the shadowing with `super.x`, because it's not a `def`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things and it does look like the conclusion you came to in your edit is correct.

There is a more circuitous way to make this work, however:

```
package rrs.scribble

import  com.badlogic.gdx.math

class Vector2(x: Float, y: Float) {
  val gdxV2 = new math.Vector2(x, y)
}

object Vector2 {
  implicit class V2(v2: Vector2)
  extends math.Vector2(v2.gdxV2)
}

object  Demo {
  import Vector2._

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val v2a = new Vector2(12.34f, 56.78f)
    val v2b = new Vector2(12.345f, 56.789f)

    println(s"v2=$v2a; v2=$v2a; sum=${v2a.add(v2b)}")
    println(s"(v2a =E(0.01) v2b)=${v2a.epsilonEquals(v2b, 0.01f)}")
    println(s"(v2a =E(0.001) v2b)=${v2a.epsilonEquals(v2b, 0.001f)}")

    // Note: This won't compile, apparently because
    // hasOppositeDirection is inherited not implemented within Vector2
```

//      println(s"v2=$v2a; sum=$sumA; hasOppositeDirection=${v2.hasOppositeDirection}")
       }
    }

Running this yields:

```
scala> rrs.scribble.Demo.main(Array[String]())
v2=rrs.scribble.Vector2@6e8d0165; v2=rrs.scribble.Vector2@6e8d0165; sum=[24.685001:113.569]
(v2a =E(0.01) v2b)=true
(v2a =E(0.001) v2b)=false
```

Unfortunately, as the comment notes, this seems to fail for methods inherited by Vector2. I'm not sure why that is, actually. However this approach has an additional advantage. You could, e.g., define `+`, `-` etc. on `V2` to enhance the usability of the underlying `gdx.math.Vector2`.